# Subcaption format with cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, subcaption, cleveref

I need to get Figure 1.1 (a) when i put `\Cref{fig:NiceImage1}`.

I have to use `\Cref{fig:NiceImage}\subref{fig:NiceImage1}` for getting same result.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup{subrefformat=parens}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\setcounter{chapter}{1}

\begin{document}

  \begin{figure}
    \centering
      \begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1}
          \caption{Nice image1}
          \label{fig:NiceImage1}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1}
          \caption{Nice image 2}
          \label{fig:NiceImage2}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1}
          \caption{Nice image 3}
          \label{fig:NiceImage3}
      \end{subfigure}
\caption{
\label{fig:NiceImage}
Three images}
\end{figure}

Figure \ref{fig:NiceImage}

Figure \ref{fig:NiceImage} \subref{fig:NiceImage1}

\Cref{fig:NiceImage}

\Cref{fig:NiceImage1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain why the label has to be within the caption environment here?

Comment: Moreover, when I use the  `wpconf` class, it seems to be necessary also in the subfigures to put the labels within the captions. You seem only to have to put the label of the caption of the "common" caption of the figure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following lines to your preamble and `\Cref{fig:NiceImage1}` will display "Figure 1.1(a)"

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple}
    \renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
```

The complete code is below:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%\captionsetup{subrefformat=parens}
%\subref{fig:NiceImage1} will not work properly...


\usepackage{cleveref}


\captionsetup[subfigure]{subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple}
    \renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}


\setcounter{chapter}{1}

\begin{document}

  \begin{figure}
    \centering
      \begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1}
          \caption{Nice image1}
          \label{fig:NiceImage1}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1}
          \caption{Nice image 2}
          \label{fig:NiceImage2}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1}
          \caption{Nice image 3}
          \label{fig:NiceImage3}
      \end{subfigure}
\caption{
\label{fig:NiceImage}
Three images}
\end{figure}

Figure \ref{fig:NiceImage}

Figure \ref{fig:NiceImage} \subref{fig:NiceImage1}

\Cref{fig:NiceImage}

\Cref{fig:NiceImage1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could remove the `subfig` package, it isn't used. Then `listofformat=simple` also has to be removed. Strictly speaking you just need to add `\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}`.

Comment: @sandu or I could edit my answer...

Comment: @sandu have now edited my answer to further elucidate which are the important bits based on Torbjorn's comment

Comment: @TorbjørnT. your comment now incorporated into the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for being a nag, but `subcaption` and `subfig` have the same purpose, so I don't see why you would use both in the same document.  `subcaption` also provides `\subref`, for example.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. OK I will edit again. My document is only based around what I have done. I had subfig first, I can no longer remember why I added subcaption. I just did a web search to find out whether everything was covered but I didn't find many references to the use of `subref`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Sorry I was being silly there: of course I don't use `subcaption` in my own document. I didn't spot the duplication when plugging in my code, and it didn't seem to cause any problems when compiling.

Comment: No, it compiled fine, and there may not be any clashes between the two (I don't know), it just seemed superfluous to add `subfig`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. you are absolutely right.

Comment: @sandu thanks sorry that was turning into a right old mess!

Comment: @TorbjørnT. How would you modify this for use with subfig package instead of subcaption? Is the \thesubfigure a different command?

Comment: @JSpen You don't have to modify it as far as I can see. The only problem is that you get double parenthesis in `\subref`. I don't know right now how to fix that though, I'd recommend asking a new question if you can't find some other question that answers it.