# PGFplots: Assigning subcaptions to the grouped plots

Tags: pgfplots, subcaption, groupplots

This is a follow-up question about [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/310403/2288), where I would like to get the same output using the conventional article class and edit the printed cross-reference text such that, for example, I would like the output of `\Cref{first}` to be `Figure 1(a)` where `Figure 1` is the output of `\Cref{main}`.

However, this MWE shows me an error

> Undefined control sequence. ...itle={\subcaption{$y=x^2$}\label{second}}]

which I don't understand where it comes from.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots,subcaption,siunitx}


\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,units}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{hyperref,cleveref}

\newlength\figureheight 
\newlength\figurewidth 
\setlength\figureheight{0.4\textwidth}
\setlength\figurewidth{0.35\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
  width=\figurewidth,
  height=\figureheight,
  scale only axis,
  title style   = {
        at={(current axis.north)},
        yshift=-2.5mm,
        font=\normalfont,
        color=black,
    text width=\figurewidth
},
  group style={
    group size=2 by 2,
    vertical sep=3cm,
    horizontal sep=1.5cm
},
  ylabel=$v_n$,xlabel=$y$,
  y unit=\m\per\s,x unit=\cm,
  domain=4:5,samples=10,
]
\nextgroupplot[title={\subcaption{Subcaption 1}\label{first}}]
  \addplot {x};
  %
  \nextgroupplot[title={\subcaption{$y=x^2$}\label{second}}]
  \addplot {x^2};
  %
  \nextgroupplot[title={\subcaption{Subcaption 3. A longer one that will break across lines.}\label{third}}]
  \addplot {-x};
  %
  \nextgroupplot[title={\subcaption{$y=x^2+4$}\label{fourth}}]
  \addplot {x^2 + 4};
\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Main caption}\label{main}
\end{figure}

\Cref{main} is the parent figure, and \Cref{first} is its child.

\end{document}
```

---

### Edit

When adding some code to my document, a different error shows up

> You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders. ...itle={\subcaption{$y=x^2$\label{second}}}]

for this MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots,subcaption,siunitx}


\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,units}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{hyperref,cleveref}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\centering

\newlength{\BorderLineWeight}       \setlength{\BorderLineWeight}{1pt}
\newlength{\MajorGridLineWeight}    \setlength{\MajorGridLineWeight}{0.1pt}
\newlength{\MinorGridLineWeight}    \setlength{\MinorGridLineWeight}{0.2pt}
\newlength{\MajorTickLineWeight}    \setlength{\MajorTickLineWeight}{1pt}
\newlength{\MinorTickLineWeight}    \setlength{\MinorTickLineWeight}{0.5pt}

\newlength{\HorSep} \setlength{\HorSep}{22pt}
\newlength{\VerSep} \setlength{\VerSep}{40pt}

\newlength{\PanelWidth} \setlength{\PanelWidth}{0.35\textwidth}
\newlength{\PanelHeight} \setlength{\PanelHeight}{0.28\textheight}

\begin{figure}
    \centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={ }}% \:\! == 4mu - 3mu = 1mu
    \begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group name=G,
        group size=2 by 2,
        y descriptions at=edge left,% make only single y axis label at left
        x descriptions at = edge bottom,
        horizontal sep=\HorSep, % adjust as needed
        vertical sep=\VerSep, 
    },
    enlargelimits=false,
    width= \PanelWidth ,%-width("300"),
    height= \PanelHeight,
    scale only axis, axis on top , grid=both,
    axis line style = {line width = \BorderLineWeight, draw=black},
    %
    tick label style = {font=\bfseries,color=black},
    tick align = outside,
    %
    xlabel  =   {r \si{\um}},
    ylabel  =   {z \si{\um}},
    %
    x label style = {at={(current axis.south)}, below=6.5mm, font=\normalfont, color=black},
    y label style = {at={(current axis.west)},above=6.5mm, font=\normalfont, color=black},
    %
    title style = {
        at={(current axis.north)},
        yshift=-2.5mm,
        font=\normalfont,
        color=black,
        %text width=\figurewidth,
    },
    %
    xmin=0, xmax=50, xtick={0,10,...,50},       minor x tick num={1}, 
    ymin=0, ymax=150, ytick={0,50,...,150},     minor y tick num={4},
    %
    major x grid style = {line width    =   \MajorGridLineWeight,dashed,black},
    minor x grid style = {line width    =   \MinorGridLineWeight,dotted,black},
    major y grid style = {line width    =   \MajorGridLineWeight,dashed,black},
    minor y grid style = {line width    =   \MinorGridLineWeight,dotted,black},
    %
    major x tick style = {line width    =   \MajorTickLineWeight,solid,black},
    minor x tick style = {line width    =   \MinorTickLineWeight,solid,black},
    major y tick style = {line width    =   \MajorTickLineWeight,solid,black},
    minor y tick style = {line width    =   \MinorTickLineWeight,solid,black},
    %
    xtick pos=left,
    ytick pos=left,
    %
    major tick length   =   1.5mm, % distance outside plot area
    minor tick length   =   1mm,
    ]
\nextgroupplot[title={\subcaption{Subcaption 1}\label{first}}]
  \addplot {x};
  %
  \nextgroupplot[title={\subcaption{$y=x^2$\label{second}}}]
  \addplot {x^2};
  %
  \nextgroupplot[title={\subcaption{Subcaption 3. A longer one that will break across lines.\label{third}}}]
  \addplot {-x};
  %
  \nextgroupplot[title={\subcaption{$y=x^2+4$\label{fourth}}}]
  \addplot {x^2 + 4};
\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Main caption}\label{main}
\end{figure}

\Cref{main} is the parent figure, and \Cref{first} is its child.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the second example. You for some reason commented the `text width` setting in the `title style`. In order to use `\subcaption` in a title you must set the `text width` I think, so just unncomment that line.

---

For the first one:

The `units` library doesn't by default pass the units to the `\si` macro of `siunitx`, so you cannot use things like

```
y unit=\m\per\s,x unit=\cm,
```

directly. To be able to use that, you must add

```
unit code/.code 2 args={\si{#1#2}}
```

to the `axis`/`groupplot` options, as given in the `pgfplots` manual.

Regarding the cross reference, see [Subcaption format with cleveref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180364/subcaption-format-with-cleveref). You need

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
```

Complete code:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots,subcaption,siunitx}


\captionsetup[subfigure]{subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,units}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{hyperref,cleveref}

\newlength\figureheight 
\newlength\figurewidth 
\setlength\figureheight{0.4\textwidth}
\setlength\figurewidth{0.35\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
  width=\figurewidth,
  height=\figureheight,
  scale only axis,
  title style   = {
        at={(current axis.north)},
        yshift=-2.5mm,
        font=\normalfont,
        color=black,
        text width=\figurewidth
},
  group style={
    group size=2 by 2,
    vertical sep=3cm,
    horizontal sep=1.5cm
},
  ylabel=$v_n$,xlabel=$y$,
  y unit=\m\per\s,x unit=\cm,
  domain=4:5,samples=10,
  unit code/.code 2 args={\si{#1#2}}
]
\nextgroupplot[title={\subcaption{Subcaption 1}\label{first}}]
  \addplot {x};
%  %
  \nextgroupplot[title={\subcaption{$y=x^2$}\label{second}}]
  \addplot {x^2};
  %
  \nextgroupplot[title={\subcaption{Subcaption 3. A longer one that will break across lines.}\label{third}}]
  \addplot {-x};
  %
  \nextgroupplot[title={\subcaption{$y=x^2+4$}\label{fourth}}]
  \addplot {x^2 + 4};
\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Main caption}\label{main}
\end{figure}

\Cref{main} is the parent figure, and \Cref{first} is its child.



\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. For my second code in the question, a different error (`You can't use \hrule here except with leaders. ...itle={\subcaption{$y=x^2$\label{second}}}]`) only happens when setting the title to be `title={\subcaption{Subcaption 1}\label{first}}` or `\captionof{subfigure}{heading\label{first}}`.  I couldn't move on with my real document because of this error.

Comment: @Diaa Try uncommenting the text width setting in the title style. I think you must set the text width to use a subcaption in a title.

Comment: You literally saved my day by this tweak.